# Are there any instances where the Egyptian gods are promiscuous?

Tags: egyptian

As we all probably know, the Greco-Roman and the Norse gods were, to put it in a mild manner, "lustful". They had extramarital affairs, took on numerous lovers without before marriage and even raped others.

Are there any instances where Egyptian gods are also promiscuous?

I am not interested in instances of incest because that is basically how the Egyptian gods got married. What I am looking for, for example, is the Egyptian gods acting like Zeus, cheating on their wives or tricking mortals into affairs like in the story of Leda.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one story that springs to mind, but it is from the Greek occupation period: Plutarch writes that Nephthys, sister of Isis, was married to Seth, but since this deity is associated with infertility, this marriage produced no children.

According to some versions of the Osiris myth, Nephthys intoxicated Osiris, her sister's husband, to conceive Anubis. In other versions, [Anubis is the illegitimate son of Ra and Nephthys](https://www.questia.com/read/107525007/a-dictionary-of-egyptian-gods-and-goddesses).

Plutarch also writes that Isis [adopted her sister's illegitimate son](http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/bazhum/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-fc7b5edc-78d2-450b-a88d-c42557950ea9/c/Organon-r2002-t31-s128-148.pdf):

> For when Isis found out that Osiris loved her sister and had relations
>   with her in mistaking her sister for herself, and when she saw a proof
>   of it in the form of a garland of clover that he had left to Nephthys
>   - she was looking for a baby, because Nephthys abandoned it at once after it had been born for fear of Seth; and when Isis found the baby
>   helped by the dogs which with great difficulties lead her there, she
>   raised him and he became her guard and ally by the name of Anubis.

However, since all these stories date from the Greek occupation, they are possibly "contaminations" from the Greek pantheon, as in earlier periods, [infidelity was very much a taboo in Ancient Egypt](https://scholarlycommons.law.northwestern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1277&context=jclc), although, as in most cultures, men were given much more lenience than women in this matter.

Comment: @Gibet I said it was a social taboo, I did not mention law. And that does not change the fact that there are no promiscuous myths in the Egyptian pantheon prior to the Greek occupation examples I have given, like the OP is asking.